# SplitViewController set as window content causes the Window to not appear

Tags: xcode, swift, macos, xcode-storyboard

Using Xcode 7.3.1 on OS X 10.11.5 using Storyboards and Swift

I'm trying to learn Swift programming for OS X so I'm trying to port an app I've already written in Java to native OS X code. The app requires the window's contents to be split vertically, which I accomplished using a BorderPane in JavaFX.

I'm trying to use an NSSplitViewController to do this in Xcode, but the Split View Controller for some reason causes the app window to not display when I run the app. If I add a simple NSViewController instead, the window is displayed just fine.

I'm using [this video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2014/212/) for reference, but the same steps (i.e. drag in a new "Vertical Split View Controller" and connect it to the Window Controller by setting as window content) do not produce the same result. I know the video's a bit old, but the process should be about the same, right?

Here is [a screenshot of my storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ptmNc.png).

TL;DR: Created a new Xcode project for OS X with Storyboards and Swift, set a SplitViewController as the window content, run the app, and the window doesn't display.

- Is there something I'm not doing?
- Is this just a bug?
- Is there anything I can do to have the window display a split view controller?

**UPDATE**

I tried subclassing `NSWindowController` to see if I can force the window to load, and lo and behold, the `windowDidLoad` method does get called, but still no window...

Here's the code for my `WindowController` subclass:

```
import Cocoa

class WindowController: NSWindowController {

    override func windowDidLoad() {
        super.windowDidLoad()
        print("The window did load.")
    }
}
```

When I run the program with that, it prints out the message "The window did load." into the output, but nothing else, so no runtime errors.

Comment: NSWindow is not a live animal.  It doesn't always have to appear at startup.  If it doesn't appear, make it appear programmatically.

Comment: How would I do that? I'm entirely new to xcode and swift

Answer (score 0):

So I solved this myself with some fiddling on the storyboard. The problem seems to originate with the way that `SplitViewController`s are configured in a storyboard. It looks like, if the child view controllers of the split view controller contain only empty views, their size is set to 0 and the windows is loaded, but its size is 0, so it is not actually displayed.

I added content to the views and the window displayed. Still have to figure out how to make it display at the size I want, but the biggest hurdle has been crossed.